# C++ PortAudio, sndfile simple program to play an audio file

Tags: c++

recently i started practicing c++ again after a long time. I have this code which opens an audio file and plays it using PortAudio and sndfile libraries. Im using Microsoft Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2022, Windows 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <portaudio.h>
#include <sndfile.h>


#define FILE_PATH "test2.wav"



// Callback function to fill the audio buffer
int audioCallback(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer,
    unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void* userData) {
    SNDFILE* file = (SNDFILE*)userData;
    float* out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    sf_count_t numFrames = framesPerBuffer;

    // Read audio data from the file and write it to the output buffer
    sf_readf_float(file, out, numFrames);

    return paContinue;
}

int main() {
    // Initialize PortAudio
    PaError err;
    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (err != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the audio file using libsndfile
    SF_INFO sfInfo;
    SNDFILE* audioFile = sf_open(FILE_PATH, SFM_READ, &sfInfo);
    if (!audioFile) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open audio file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up PortAudio stream parameters
    PaStream* stream;
    PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice();
    outputParameters.channelCount = sfInfo.channels;
    outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(outputParameters.device)->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = nullptr;

    // Open the PortAudio stream
    err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, nullptr, &outputParameters, sfInfo.samplerate, paFramesPerBufferUnspecified, paClipOff, audioCallback, audioFile);
    if (err != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Start the audio stream
    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Playing audio. Press Enter to stop..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    // Stop and close the stream
    err = Pa_StopStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
    }
    err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the audio file
    sf_close(audioFile);

    // Terminate PortAudio
    Pa_Terminate();

    return 0;
}
```

It works and plays the test2.wav file that is located in the same folder as the main.cpp.
However when i split the code into header and cpp files and use OOP approach, the code still runs fine but I can't hear any audio? The implementation is still the same, it's just calling the AudioPlayer class from the main.cpp. Any ideas on why is that happening?

```
// AudioPlayer.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <portaudio.h>
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <string>

class AudioPlayer {
public:
    AudioPlayer(const std::string& filePath);
    ~AudioPlayer();

    bool Initialize();
    bool Start();
    bool Stop();

private:
    SNDFILE* audioFile;
    PaStream* audioStream;
    SF_INFO sfInfo;
};
```

```
// AudioPlayer.cpp
#include "AudioPlayer.h"

AudioPlayer::AudioPlayer(const std::string& filePath) {
    audioFile = nullptr;
    audioStream = nullptr;

    // Initialize PortAudio
    if (Pa_Initialize() != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "PortAudio initialization failed." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Open the audio file using libsndfile
    audioFile = sf_open(filePath.c_str(), SFM_READ, &sfInfo);
    if (!audioFile) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open audio file: " << filePath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Set up PortAudio stream parameters
    PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice();
    outputParameters.channelCount = sfInfo.channels;
    outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(outputParameters.device)->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = nullptr;

    // Open the PortAudio stream
    if (Pa_OpenStream(&audioStream, nullptr, &outputParameters, sfInfo.samplerate, paFramesPerBufferUnspecified, paClipOff, nullptr, this) != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open PortAudio stream." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}

AudioPlayer::~AudioPlayer() {
    // Close the audio file
    if (audioFile) {
        sf_close(audioFile);
    }

    // Close and terminate PortAudio
    if (audioStream) {
        Pa_StopStream(audioStream);
        Pa_CloseStream(audioStream);
        Pa_Terminate();
    }
}

bool AudioPlayer::Initialize() {
    return audioFile && audioStream;
}

bool AudioPlayer::Start() {
    if (audioFile && audioStream) {
        if (Pa_StartStream(audioStream) == paNoError) {
            std::cout << "Playing audio. Press Enter to stop..." << std::endl;
            std::cin.get();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool AudioPlayer::Stop() {
    if (audioStream) {
        return Pa_StopStream(audioStream) == paNoError;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "AudioPlayer.h"

int main() {
    const std::string filePath = "test2.wav"; // Use your audio file path

    AudioPlayer audioPlayer(filePath);

    if (audioPlayer.Initialize()) {
        if (audioPlayer.Start()) {
            audioPlayer.Stop();
        }
    } else {
        std::cerr << "AudioPlayer initialization failed." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

ChatGPT was not able to help me. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Your program exits (returns from `main`) shortly/instantly after starting playback of the audio. Why you don't hear anything shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: "ChatGPT was not able to help me." - Why would you expect a mindless chat-bot that doesn't know how to code but just strings text together into something that looks reasonable, to be able to help?

Comment: This is not `C` code.  Do not use the `C` tag for `C++` code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for replying, but the program awaits until I press Enter, so it does not exit, i should be able to hear the audio.

Comment: Is the audio playback happening in a different thread? If not, then `cin.get` doesn't do anything but pause everything until a key press and then the program exits.

Comment: @JesperJuhl im not starting any threads explicitly, so i guess not, this is the start method:

bool AudioPlayer::Start() {
    if (audioFile && audioStream) {
        if (Pa_StartStream(audioStream) == paNoError) {
            std::cout << "Playing audio. Press Enter to stop..." << std::endl;
            std::cin.get();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: And just after you print "Playing audio" your program halts *everything* (including audio playback) and waits for a key press and then you return from `main`. How do you expect to hear any audio then? What code do you expect to be running to play that audio while your program is paused? Or after it exits?

Comment: @JesperJuhl i don't understand why does it work when i run it all from main.cpp instead of splitting it into header and cpp files? It works  like that and I can hear the audio even tho the cin waits for the user input. Im just doing it for an exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the error. When opening the audio stream i didnt set the audio callback function and audioFile correctly:

```
    // Open the PortAudio stream
    if (Pa_OpenStream(&audioStream, nullptr, &outputParameters, sfInfo.samplerate, paFramesPerBufferUnspecified, paClipOff, nullptr, this) != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open PortAudio stream." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

last two arguments to the Pa_OpenStream function should be set to AudioCallback method, and previously opened audio file:

```
    // Open the PortAudio stream
    if (Pa_OpenStream(&audioStream, nullptr, &outputParameters, sfInfo.samplerate, paFramesPerBufferUnspecified, paClipOff, AudioCallback, audioFile) != paNoError) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open PortAudio stream." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

Thanks everyone for help!!